# ListView of SeekBars

Tags: android, listview, android-studio, arraylist, seekbar

I wonder how I can make a ListView of ArrayList of SeekBar
(which i can 'add' more SeekBars to the list on button click  )
I am a beginner so I've been trying for hours. that is the best I could do but I don't know whether I can even do something with that :

```
    ArrayList<SeekBar> seekbarlist=new ArrayList<SeekBar>();
    ListView listseekbars = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listprog);
    final ArrayAdapter<SeekBar> seekbardapter = new 
    ArrayAdapter<SeekBar>
    (this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,android.R.id.text1,seekbarlist);
    listseekbars.setAdapter(seekbardapter);
```

i'll be more than glad to get some help :)
thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably don't want to display a list of SeekBars. You want to display a list of values AS SeekBars.

You'll need to make a custom adapter, and a custom list item layout.

the custom list item is just a seekbar:

seekbar_list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SeekBar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/seekBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:max="100">

</SeekBar>
```

Custom Adapter:

```
    private class SeekBarAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Integer>{

    List<Integer> data;
    int resource;

    SeekBarAdapter(Context context, int layoutResource, List<Integer> data){
        super(context, layoutResource, data);
        this.data = data;
        this.resource = layoutResource;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

        Integer value = data.get(position);

        if (convertView == null){
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(resource, parent);
        }

        SeekBar sb = convertView.findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
        sb.setProgress(value);

        sb.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean wasInitiatedByUser) {
                // do what you want with the edited values here.
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

then to implement:

```
ArrayList<Integer> yourvalues = new ArrayList<>();
ListView listseekbars = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listprog);
SeekBarAdapter seekBarAdapter = new SeekBarAdapter(this, R.layout.seekbar_list_item, yourvalues);
listseekbars.setAdapter(seekBarAdapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need to do is use a `RecyclerView` instead of a `ListView` The difference is that you can make a layout file for each of the items and than add those items to the `RecyclerView`.